# using foreach inside foreach and losing the variable from the first foreach, mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to look in a collection for every "open" project, than find for every project the signd in users in a different collection. But after the first `.finally()` the variable ´code = users´ is empty instead to save the users from the `.foreach`.

```
var code = "";
var project_details = "";
var users = "";
var endcode= "";

  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    //find projects which are open
    let collection = db.collection('project');
    collection.find({ status: "open" }).forEach(function (project) {
      //find users that signd in for that project
      let collection = db.collection('users');
      collection.find({ project: project.id }).forEach(function (user) {
          users = user.name + users;
      })
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
        .finally(() => {
          code = users;
        });
    //console.log(code); is empty and this point
    //foreach project
    project_details = "Project:" + project.name + ", Users: " + code;
    endcode = endcode + project_details;
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
    .finally(() => {
    res.render('projects', { code: endcode });
    client.close();
    });
    //////
  });
```

The expected result in `endcode` should be `"Project: Projectname1, Users: User1,User2 Project: Projectname2, Users: User3,User4 ...`.

How can I prevent from losing the written variable `code`?

Comment: you did not wait for the `collection.find` function finish. `console.log` is executed before `collection.find` has finished execution

Comment: Even if I place the `console.log()` inside the first `.finally()`, when I'm calling it in the second `.finally()` its still empty..